# Need to read the contents of a file name inside another file in JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have a file name created in a step.. Say the file name is ABC.DEF. The content of the file may have another file name or filenames listed in each line as a record....

let the contents of the file ABC.DEF be
XYZ.AAA

I need make use of the file name XYZ.AAA in the next step..

Please let me know is there any utility to perform this.. or any other way of doing this through SORT utility...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My output file has an input file which i need to point to another step as input file in JCL SORT ? How can I proceed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993624/my-output-file-has-an-input-file-which-i-need-to-point-to-another-step-as-input)

Comment: yes its same requirement as posted please help me with any resolution ?

Comment: Search the internet with this string: "Search a filename in another file Using DFSORT"

Comment: using above "Search a filename in another file Using DFSORT" i can search the file how can i use this file in my next step ?

Comment: Try this search string: "read a filename and create JCL Using DFSORT"

Comment: thank you NicC but requirement is i need to read the file inside input file and point this file to next step no need to create one more JCL.

Comment: If you had read fully you would have found that that is not possible. Once submitted the JCL is fixed. In fact, it is discarded before execution as the reader/interpreter converts it into control blocks to be used by the iniitator running your job. What you can do is have the program that needs the dataset (it is not a file) that is specified within that dataset read the dataset name and  then dynamically allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

Parse file abc.def for the needed info (using sort, rexx, uss or a pgm to be written in any available language) and dynamically create a jcl which you submit afterwards using e.g. IKJEFT01.

Just an idea, completely unverified,

br johann